# Nestjs, How to get entity table name?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

How to get entity table name ? (ex: member-pre-sale-detail)
I want to set table comment

```
// Seeder: Clear & set Comment
export default class ClearAllSeed implements Seeder {
    public async run(factory: Factory, connection: Connection): Promise<void> {


        const deleteEntities = [
            {table: OrderHead, comment: '訂單/主表'},
       ]

       for(const entity of deleteEntities){
            await connection
                .createQueryBuilder()
                .delete()
                .from(entity.table)
                .execute();

            await connection
                // >>>> but table name is MemberPreSaleDetail not member-pre-sale-detail
                .query(`alter table ${entity.table.name} comment '${entity.comment}'`);
        }
   }
}

// Sampel Entity
@Entity('member-pre-sale-detail')
export class MemberPreSaleDetail {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({unsigned: true})
  id?: number;

  @Column({comment: '幾批(整批)', type: 'mediumint', default: 0})
  batchQty: number;
}
```

### Expected behavior

get the 'member-pre-sale-detail' string

### Environment

Nest version: 7.0.7
 
For Tooling issues:
- Node version: v14.5.0
- Platform:  Mac

Comment: hmm I am not sure how this `@Entity` decorator works but I think that you can try sth like this :`entity.constructor.name`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am guessing you are using TypeORM. In that case:

You could get the entity metadata by calling `connection.getMetadata(MemberPreSaleDetail)`.

This method returns an [EntityMetadata](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_metadata_entitymetadata_.entitymetadata.html), which has `name`, `tableName` and `givenTableName` properties. For your usecase I guess you could simply use `givenTableName`.

Answer (score 0):

you got to easy way

`getManager().getRepository(User).metadata.tableName`

OR

extends the User class with the BaseEntity from typeorm and do

`user.getRepository().metadata.tableName`